# What's the life time of Azure Function app?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

Suppose. I have a static variable dtTime which set to DateTime.Now when it initial start up. and I have code to output dtTime to log file. I would like to know, Will variable dtTime change? and how often it changes?

```
static DateTime dtTime = DateTime.Now;
```

Comment: You should consider external storage such as Azure Tables, or a DB. Durable Functions is another option for long running or Orchestrated processes that require _state_ persistence

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are speaking persistence of your token in the static variable.

What you can do is when you first fetch the token, store the token as well as the expiry datetime (minus 5 minutes?) into the static variable.

Then for each function execution, check if the token field is null or the current datetime is > expiry datetime. If no, then use the static field. If yes, then fetch the new token.

Assuming you are in consumption plan, if there is no activity on the function, it will switch off the server after around 20 mins(approx). When a new trigger comes in, a new server will start up with empty static variables. The above pseudo code will ensure that you renew your token in such a case.

You also need to be aware that if you function scales to more instances, each one will maintain its own static variable memory (which won't be a problem if the previous tokens are not invalidated when you request a new one).

For .NET some simple pseudo code will look like

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;

private static string accesstoken;
private static HttpClient httpclient = new HttpClient();

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");
    string responseMessage;
    if (accesstoken == null){
//      Fetch your new token here and store in accesstoken
        responseMessage = "Stored access token in Cache";
        log.LogInformation($"Stored in Cache :{accesstoken}");
    }
    else
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Got data from cache. {accesstoken}");  
        responseMessage = "Retrieved data from cache."; 
    }

    return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
}
```

For Python you can refer to [Caching in python](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#global-variables)

Answer (score 0):

I do not think, you need to think about LifeTime of Function App Here.

Whatever function app you deploy is abstracted and infrastructure is managed by Azure. Azure server times runs on UTC by default.

Best practice is to use UTC time in server context, you can find the list of supported time zones [`here`](https://sajeetharan.com/2019/11/12/how-to-set-timezone-in-azure-app-service/).

Answer (score 0):

Since the Azure trigger function is static, the date time variable if referenced as a static variable outside of the scope of the the function will obtain the current date and time whenever the function is triggered. So the date time will change for each time the function is triggered. This seems to be the most logical way I understand the purpose of this question.